Convergence of Latent Class Linear Mixed Model with LCMM in R with multiple outcome variables
I am seeking help getting my latent class linear mixed models to converge using the LCMM package in R.
I’m working with a large longitudinal dataset on cognitive functioning in Parkinson’s disease, and I'm trying to identify cognitive profiles from data points spanning from 0 to 10 years. Each year, multiple cognitive tests are administered to assess cognitive domains. This leads to 8 independent outcome variables. My dataset contains 732 Parkinson’s disease patients, some of them have missing values at datapoints.
I’m using a latent class linear mixed model with the lcmm package in R to model the cognitive changes over time. Here’s the model setup, where I’ve included only 3 cognitive variables:
mlclmm_model <- multlcmm(

  fixed = DVT_SDM + DVT_TOTAL_RECALL + DVT_SFTANIM ~ YEAR + age,

  random = ~ YEAR | PATNO,

  subject = "PATNO",

  data = Data_plot,

  ng = 1,

  maxiter = 200,

  link = "linear"

)

 
This the output of the summary of the model:


General latent class mixed model

     fitted by maximum likelihood method

multlcmm(fixed = DVT_SDM + DVT_TOTAL_RECALL + DVT_SFTANIM ~ YEAR +

    age, random = ~YEAR | PATNO, subject = "PATNO", ng = 1, link = "linear",

    data = Data_plot, maxiter = 200)

Statistical Model:

     Dataset: Data_plot

     Number of subjects: 732

     Number of observations: 11085

     Number of latent classes: 1

     Number of parameters: 13  

     Link functions: Linear for DVT_SDM  

                     Linear for DVT_TOTAL_RECALL  

                     Linear for DVT_SFTANIM  

Iteration process:

     Maximum number of iteration reached without convergence

     Number of iterations:  200

     Convergence criteria: parameters= 4.8e-08

                         : likelihood= 1.5e-11

                         : second derivatives= 1

Goodness-of-fit statistics:

     maximum log-likelihood: -40602.06  

     AIC: 81230.12  

     BIC: 81289.86  

Maximum Likelihood Estimates:

Fixed effects in the longitudinal model:

                              coef Se Wald p-value

intercept (not estimated)  0.00000                

YEAR                      -0.08738                

age                       -0.02394                

Variance-covariance matrix of the random-effects:

(the variance of the first random effect is not estimated)

                 intercept YEAR | PATNOTRUE

intercept          1.00000                

YEAR | PATNOTRUE   0.46015          3.24264

                          DVT_SDM DVT_TOTAL_RECALL DVT_SFTANIM

Residual standard error:  1.80111  4.34913          4.04510  

Parameters of the link functions:

                              coef Se Wald p-value

DVT_SDM-Linear 1          51.61487                

DVT_SDM-Linear 2           3.70604                

DVT_TOTAL_RECALL-Linear 1 49.70980                

DVT_TOTAL_RECALL-Linear 2  2.37214                

DVT_SFTANIM-Linear 1      55.30213                

DVT_SFTANIM-Linear 2       2.39356

Issue:
The model reaches the maximum number of iterations (200) without converging.
The convergence criteria are extremely small (parameters=4.8e-8, likelihood=1.5e-11), but convergence still isn’t achieved.
The output reports second derivatives = 1, which suggests there might be problems with numerical stability or non-identifiability. I have also tried the model with more variables, but this also does not lead to convergence.
Given the complexity of my model, I’m struggling with convergence. What could be the potential causes of this issue? Are there any best practices or strategies for ensuring convergence in this type of model? Should I consider fixing parameters to zero (e.g., spline coefficients), or is there another approach to resolving this? Any advice on improving model stability or improving the convergence process would be greatly appreciated. I would eventually like to take more cognitive variables into account, instead of only 3.
